# Suchbegriffe zum Verständnis der Verwendungsregeln möchten

Tags: verb

Ich lerne Deutsch und ich weiß nur wenig.

Ich verstehe die Bedeutung von

"Ich möchte einen Kaffee" und "Ich möchte wandern gehen"

aber wonach kann ich suchen, um die Regeln für den letzteren Satz zu verstehen, bei dem ich zwei Verben gestapelt habe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Verb gehen kann mit vielen anderen Verben im Infinitiv kombiniert werden: *einkaufen gehen, schwimmen gehen, joggen gehen, spazieren gehen* und viele weitere. So eine Gruppe funktioniert dann wie **ein** Verb. Die Bedeutung ist *die Wohnung verlassen um etwas außerhalb zu tun*.

Manchmal werden Gruppen aus zwei Verben auch in einem Wort geschrieben: *stehenbleiben, jemanden kennenlernen*, aber die Regeln für das Zusammenschreiben sind kompliziert.

Okay, nehmen wir also *wandern gehen* als **ein** komplexes Verb. Das kann man wie irgendein anderes Verb auch mit einem Modalverb kombinieren:

> Ich **kann** heute nicht **wandern gehen**, ich muss für die Prüfung lernen.

In deinem Beispiel ist *möchte* das Modalverb.

Das ist der einfache Fall. Für zusammengesetzte Zeiten wie zum Beispiel das Perfekt gibt es wieder spezielle Regeln.

Das **Verb-Stapeln am Satzende** ist eine typische Eigenschaft deutscher Sätze. In den Grammatiken heißt das **Satzklammer**. Im (normalen) Aussagesatz kommt immer das finite Verb (= das Verb mit der Personen-Endung) auf die Position 2, und der Rest der Verbalgruppe kommt ans Satzende, und dazwischen kommen die Objekte, Ort- und Zeitangaben und alles andere.

Der *Rest der Verbalgruppe* - auch "Verbverband" – am Satzende kann aus einem bis (theoretisch) vier Infinitiven oder Partizipien-II bestehen.

Beispiele:

- Ich will schlafen: *Infinitiv*
- Ich habe gut geschlafen: *Partizip II*
- Ich möchte noch etwas liegen bleiben (= noch im Bett bleiben): *Infinitiv + Infinitiv*
- Ich bin noch bis 8 Uhr liegen geblieben: *Infinitiv + Partizip*
- Ich musste mich geschlagen geben: *Partizip + Infinitiv* = idiomatisch, *sich geschlagen geben* = to surrender
- Ich habe mich geschlagen gegeben: *Partizip + Partizip*
- Er wird morgen wieder arbeiten gehen müssen: *Infinitiv + Infinitiv + Infinitiv* – "*too sophisticated*" / zu kompliziert in normalem Deutsch, besser: *Er muss morgen wieder arbeiten gehen* oder *Er muss morgen wieder zur Arbeit* oder *Er muss morgen wieder arbeiten*, denn *morgen* + *Präsens* = Zukunft [*werden + Infinitiv* versteht man meistens als eine Vermutung, es ist gleichbedeutend mit *wahrscheinlich*]

und so weiter.

Gruppen von drei Infinitiven/Partizipien am Satzende kommen tatsächlich nicht selten vor, aber man versucht das zu vermeiden.

In Nebensätzen kommt zusätzlich das finite Verb ganz an das Satzende: *Er hat mir gesagt, dass er am Wochenende angeln gehen will.* In solchen Konstruktionen kann es auch vier Verben hintereinander geben, aber wir versuchen das zu vermeiden; manchmal geht es nicht anders, um die gemeinte Bedeutung genau zu treffen.

Abschreckende Beispiele ("*horrifying examples*") dazu findet man in großer Zahl in Wiktionary, zum Beispiel hier: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:liegen_bleiben ,
mindestens 80% der Beispiele dort sind eher frankensteinmäßig zusammengetackert als normales Deutsch. Es sind Labor-Sätze, kein Mensch spricht so.

Answer (score 1):

Dieselbe Reihung von Verben gibt es auch in anderen Sprachen, so z.B. im Englischen ("I want to learn rock climbing.") oder Französischen ("Je veux aller chercher mon livre."). Wie ist das in deiner Muttersprache? Möglicherweise gibt es ähnliche Reihungen von Verben dort auch. Dann kannst du, wie das im Deutschen funktioniert, sehr wahrscheinlich mit Hilfe ähnlicher Konstruktionen in deiner Muttersprache verstehen.

Ansonsten gibt es keine allgemeinen Regeln, wie man aus einem beliebigen Satz ableiten kann, nach welchen grammatischen Begriffen man suchen muss, um ihn zu verstehen. Oft hilft es, im Wörterbuch oder in einer Grammatik nach dem entsprechenden Wort zu suchen. Manche Wörter, wie das Modalverb *mögen*, haben eine besondere Bedeutung und ihre Verwendung wird (überblicksartig) im Wörterbuch und (ausführlicher) in der Grammatik erklärt.

Comment: Fremdsprachen lernen durch (äußerliche) Analogiebildung mit der Muttersprache ist nicht unbedingt die beste Idee. Bei relativ ähnlichen Sprachen wie Deutsch und Englisch/Französisch mag das oft noch gehen, aber auch längst nicht immer, und je weiter man sich entfernt, desto höher ist die Chance, dass etwas, was zufällig ähnlich aussieht, eigentlich im Kern anders funktioniert.

Answer (score 0):

Ich danke Ihnen für Ihre Hilfe.  Beide Erklärungen waren hilfreich.  Annatar machte auch einen guten Punkt.

Aus Ihren Antworten konnte ich Folgendes herausfinden: [https://www.vistawide.com/german/grammar/german_verbs.htm#:~:text=The%20infinitive%20in%20German&text=The%20infinitive%20is%20typically%20used,finite%20(conjugated)%20verb%20form.&text=The%20infinitive%20is%20also%20used,a%20sentence%20or%20independent%20clause](https://www.vistawide.com/german/grammar/german_verbs.htm#:%7E:text=The%20infinitive%20in%20German&text=The%20infinitive%20is%20typically%20used,finite%20(conjugated)%20verb%20form.&text=The%20infinitive%20is%20also%20used,a%20sentence%20or%20independent%20clause).

Complete German Grammer, 2nd edition by Ed Swick has this sentence and example: "Double infinitives are not used in English, but this unique structure of German verbs is very simple to understand and use .... Ich habe es vekaufen wollen."  So perhaps "double infinitives" would be a good search term.